# SpatialRefSys as foreign key

Tags: spatial-database, geodjango

Using the working stuff reported [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/GeoDjangoExtras), I've written the following django model:

```py
from django.contrib.gis.models import SpatialRefSys

class LandCover(models.Model):
    shp_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom_srid = models.ForeignKey(SpatialRefSys)
```

But syncdb gives me this error :

```
[user@host]$ ./manage.py syncdb
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
myapp.landcover: 'geom_srid' has a relation with model <class 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.models.SpatialRefSys'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a documented behavior as of [Django 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.2/#spatialrefsys-and-geometrycolumns-models).

Adding `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` should nail it.

Comment: Thank you. But as reported in django doc, shouldn't be better to use: `from django.db import connection
SpatialRefSys = connection.ops.spatial_ref_sys()

class LandCover(models.Model):
    shp_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom_srid = models.ForeignKey(SpatialRefSys)`? This seems to work, or at least ./manage shell does not complain about a non conformant model...

Comment: Does this work even when you remove `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'` from your `INSTALLED_APPS`?It shouldn't since `django.contrib.gis.models.SpatialRefSys` == `connection.ops.spatial_ref_sys()` == `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis.models.SpatialRefSys` when your default connection backends is `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`.

Comment: I didn't add `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` to my `INSTALLED_APPS` variable and I always had `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis` as my default database engine. But I said "seems" to work because it does not complain when I run ./manage shell...further tests are needed in order to see if this ForeignKey constraint works correctly at all...